# Scheduled posts not showing in Sanity calendar

Tags: plugins, sanity

I installed Sanity Content Calendar using `sanity install content-calendar`. Under *Desk* tab, scheduling works as the *Publish* button becomes a *Schedule* button but once I schedule a post, nothing seems to show up under *Calendar* tab and the calendar is still empty as if I didn't schedule anything.

I followed recommendations however as I had to specify `type` fields in `./config/content-calendar.json`:

```json
{
  "types": [
    {
        "type": "post",
        "field": "publishedAt"
    },
    {
        "type": "analysis",
        "field": "publishedAt"
    }
  ],
  "filterWarnings": [{}]
}
```

So why is that ?

Comment: It looks like there is an open issue on GitHub rep https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity-plugin-content-calendar/issues/29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I went on the repository issue, I found a solution in the comments.

Indeed I just had to specify a title for each type but it was not told in this [post](https://www.sanity.io/blog/calendar-plugin).

This should look like this in `./config/content-calendar.json`:

```json
{
  "types": [
    {
        "type": "post",
        "field": "publishedAt",
        "titleField": "title"
    },
    {
        "type": "analysis",
        "field": "publishedAt",
        "titleField": "title"
    }
  ],
  "filterWarnings": [{}]
}
```

Comment: Woopsy it was not in the documentation but from this article: https://www.sanity.io/blog/calendar-plugin